# ¿La keyword "super" es innecesaria en este tipo de escenarios?

Tags: java

estoy programando en Java y me surgió una duda con respecto a la palabra reservada "super". En los códigos que muestro a continuación se puede ver que cambié la palabra super por this.

Tengo entendido que con super accedemos a los atributos de la superclase y sus métodos. Pero si se tiene una subclase que extiende de esta superclase, tendrá sus atributos y métodos. Entonces, ¿qué tan necesario se hace usar la palabra super y no this?

[image: Código con super]

[image: Código con this]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sabes, al utilizar `super` en un contexto, estás accediendo a los miembros (atributos o métodos) de la superclase en lugar de los miembros de la subclase.

En el ejemplo que propones no se produce una situación de conflicto que haga imprescindible el uso de la llamada super. Sin embargo, si tiras del hilo de este razonamiento podrás deducir cuáles son los casos donde el uso de super es necesario o como mínimo recomendable:

- Para acceder a un **método sobreescrito**: si tu subclase ha sobrescrito un método de la superclase, al usar `super` puedes llamar al método de la superclase desde la subclase.
- Para acceder al **constructor de la superclase**: si tu superclase tiene un constructor que acepta argumentos y la subclase también tiene un constructor, puedes utilizar `super` para llamar al constructor de la superclase y asegurarte de que la inicialización de la superclase se realice correctamente pasándole argumentos recibidos por el constructor de la subclase.
- Para **evitar ambigüedades**: en los casos donde existan nombres duplicados entre la superclase y la subclase, por ejemplo nombres de atributos, el uso de `super` te permite especificar explícitamente que deseas acceder al miembro de la superclase.

Comment: Lo entiendo perfectamente. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia directa en realidad a simple vista parece no estar, pero sí la puedes notar cuando comienzas a utilizar sobrecarga y necesitas utilizar por alguna razón uno u otro método ya sea del padre o del hijo.

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente clase **A** donde tendrá un único método llamado `miAcción()` que tiene la tarea de sumar un 1 al valor que ingresa:

```
class A {
    public int miAccion(int valor) {
        return valor + 1;
    }
}
```

Ahora crearemos una segunda clase **B** que va a heredar de la clase **A** por lo tanto éste mismo tendrá ya el método `miAccion()` pero le vamos a sobrecargar el método agregando una funcionalidad extra que será una suma de 10:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public int miAccion(int valor) {
        int res = super.miAccion(valor);
        return res + 10;
    }

    public void mostrarMiAccionThis() {
        System.out.println("Resultado de this: " + this.miAccion(1));
    }
    
    public void mostrarMiAccionSuper() {
        System.out.println("Resultado de super: " + super.miAccion(1));
    }
}
```

Según lo que ahora se tiene verás que hay un resultado diferente utilizando el **this** o el **super** porque una es de la misma clase y la otra de la superclase o clase padre.

Si hacemos una prueba mostrando los valores verás lo siguiente:

```
B b = new B();
b.mostrarMiAccionThis();
b.mostrarMiAccionSuper();
```

Resultado:

> Resultado de this: 12
> Resultado de super: 2

En este ejemplo puedes ver que en realidad en muchas ocasiones necesitaras usar tanto **super** como **this** sobre todo en la sobrecarga. ;)

Comment: Oh, entiendo. ¡Gracias! :')